# What is the name of the polyhedron you obtain by truncating one vertex of an octahedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

How do you call in English a nine faces polyhedron looking like a (more or less) regular octahedron but having *one and only one* vertex truncated?

[image: octahedron with one vertice truncated]

A [truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron) has all its faces truncated. And an "octahedron frustum" does not raise many results on Google.

Comment: Maybe an *enneahedron*?

Comment: There are so many, many things that one can do to convert old polyhedra into new ones, and not enough names. This one, I feel confident, is unnamed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Bernard and  Lee. My drawing could have caused confusion, but in my particular case the "base" is a square, and the bottom faces are trapezoidal, so this could be a "dual elongated square pyramid". I've self-answered below. Feel free to comment there if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a square base, and according to Wikipedia, this could be a [*Dual elongated square pyramid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_pyramid#Dual_polyhedron):

> The dual of the elongated square pyramid has 9 faces: 4 triangular, 1
>   square and 4 trapezoidal.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

As to @SylvainLeroux: the dual of the dual is the polytope itself. Thus combinatorically it even can be seen as the elongeted square pyramid itself.

In order to put it metrically more correct, you else could speak of a monotruncated octahedron.

--- rk